# How to dynamically change a row?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to find a way to dynamically change the dates of the Earliest Date field so if the **TotalShipped** = **TotalOrdered** then I want to take the earliest date where the two fields don't equal each other.

This an example of what the data currently looks like

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  fsono INT
  , NAME VARCHAR(30)    
  , TS int
  , [TO] int   
  , [Date] date  
);

INSERT INTO mytable (fsono, NAME, TS, [TO], [Date])
  VALUES
    (1,'039069',1,1,'2019-3-19')
    , (2,'039069',1,1,'2019-3-19')
    , (3,'039069',1,0,'2019-3-20')
    , (4,'039069',1,0,'2019-3-21');

SELECT 
  sorels.fsono,
  sorels.finumber,
  sorels.frelease,
  fshipbook+fshipbuy+fshipmake as totalshipped,
  fjoqty + fbook + fbqty as totalordered,
  sorels.fduedate
FROM m2mdata35.dbo.sorels   
INNER JOIN somast on sorels.fsono=somast.fsono   
INNER JOIN soitem on sorels.fsono=soitem.fsono AND sorels.finumber=soitem.finumber   
LEFT JOIN inmastx on soitem.fpartno=inmastx.fpartno and soitem.fpartrev=inmastx.frev  
LEFT JOIN jomast on sorels.fstatus=jomast.fjobno 
LEFT JOIN slcdpmx on somast.fcustno=slcdpmx.fcustno  
LEFT JOIN syphon ON somast.fcontact=syphon.fcontact AND somast.fcustno=syphon.fcsourceid 
WHERE LEFT(somast.fstatus,1)<>'C' and fsocoord<>'IFP' and fsocoord<>'711' 
and somast.fsono='039069' 
Order By sorels.fsono, sorels.fduedate, sorels.finumber, sorels.frelease
```

This is what I'd like the results to look like

```
CREATE TABLE myresults (
  fsono INT 
  , NAME VARCHAR(30)
  , TS int  
  , [TO] int   
  , [Date] date  
  , Earliest_Date date 
);

INSERT INTO myresults (fsono, NAME, TS, [TO], [Date], Earliest_Date)
  VALUES
    (1,'039069',1,1,'2019-3-19','2019-3-20')
    , (2,'039069',1,1,'2019-3-19','2019-3-20')
    , (3,'039069',1,0,'2019-3-20','2019-3-20')
    , (4,'039069',1,0,'2019-3-21','2019-3-20');
```

Comment: What does MyTable have to do with that query? Also, you have functions in your where clause wrapped around columns. That renders your query nonSARGable and no amount of indexing is going to help you.

Comment: @SeanLange Just some sample data so people can replicate what I'm trying to do.

Comment: OK but that sample data is completely out of context and at least for me makes no sense about how it relates here. What you really to post is some sample data relevant to the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a common table expression and joined on that table.

```
;with cte1 as (
SELECT Distinct 
sorels.fsono,
min(sorels.fduedate ) Over(Partition by sorels.fsono, Case when fshipbook+fshipbuy+fshipmake <> sorels.fjoqty + sorels.fbook + sorels.fbqty then 1 else 0 end ) as EarliestDate 
-----------

FROM m2mdata35.dbo.sorels     
INNER JOIN somast on sorels.fsono=somast.fsono  

WHERE LEFT(somast.fstatus,1)<>'C' 
and fsocoord<>'IFP' and fsocoord<>'711' 
and fshipbook+fshipbuy+fshipmake <> sorels.fjoqty + sorels.fbook + sorels.fbqty
)

select sorels.fsono, sorels.finumber, sorels.frelease,
Case when fshipbook+fshipbuy+fshipmake <> sorels.fjoqty + sorels.fbook + sorels.fbqty then 'T' else 'F' end as BackOrd,
sorels.fduedate, cte1.EarliestDate, 
--/*
sorels.fjoqty ,
sorels.fbqty,
fshipbook+fshipbuy+fshipmake as totalshipped,
sorels.fjoqty + sorels.fbook + sorels.fbqty as totalordered,
inwork.fcpro_id,
inwork.fdept,
soitem.fsource as 'soitem.fsource',
sorels.funetprice,
sorels.fshptoaddr as 'sorels.fshptoaddr',
somast.fshptoaddr as 'somast.fshptoaddr',
syaddr.fccompany,
sorels.fstatus ,
jomast.fjobno,
jomast.fstatus AS 'jomast.fstatus', 
soitem.fenumber,
soitem.fquantity,
sorels.forderqty,   
somast.fcustno,
soitem.fac,
soitem.fpartno,
soitem.fpartrev,
incros.fcrosspart,
somast.fcompany,
slcdpmx.fcusrchr1,
left(somast.fcfname,1) as 'somast.fcfname',
somast.fcontact,
syphon.fctitle,
soitem.fgroup as 'soitem.fgroup',
soitem.fprodcl as 'soitem.fprodcl',
soitem.manualplan,
--inmast.fsource as 'soitem.fsource',
inmast.fgroup AS 'inmast.fgroup',
inmast.fbuyer as 'inmast.fbuyer' ,
inmast.fprodcl as 'inmast.fpodcl',
inmast.fnusrcur1 as 'inmast.fnusrcur1' ,
inmast.fproqty as 'inmast.fproqty',
inmast.fbook as 'inmast.fbook',
inmast.fonhand 'inmast.fonhand',
inmast.frevdt 'inmast.frevdt',   
somast.fshipvia,
cspopup.fcpoptext,
somast.fstatus AS 'somast.fstatus',
somast.fsocoord,
somast.fordername,
somast.fcustpono,
somast.fcusrchr1 AS 'somast.fcusrchr1',
somast.fcusrchr2,
somast.fcusrchr3,
somast.forderdate,
sorels.fpostatus,   
sorels.fshipbook,
sorels.fshipbuy,
sorels.fshipmake,
sorels.fshpbefdue,
sorels.fsplitshp,
soitem.fshipitem,
soitem.fmultiple,
sorels.fstatus as 'sorels.fstatus',
sorels.fshipbook + sorels.fshipbuy + sorels.fshipmake AS 'qtyshipped',
sorels.forderqty - sorels.fshipbook + sorels.fshipbuy + sorels.fshipmake AS 'qtyship', 
jodrtg.fnqty_comp - sorels.fshipbook + sorels.fshipbuy + sorels.fshipmake - jodrtg.fnqty_move AS 'availtoship'
--*/

from sorels 
LEFT JOIN cte1 on sorels.fsono=cte1.fsono 
INNER JOIN soitem on sorels.fsono+sorels.finumber=soitem.fsono+soitem.finumber  
INNER JOIN somast on sorels.fsono=somast.fsono  

--/*
LEFT JOIN cspopup ON 'SHIPVIA             '+somast.fshipvia=cspopup.fcpopkey+cspopup.fcpopval
LEFT JOIN inmast on soitem.fpartno+soitem.fpartrev=inmast.fpartno+inmast.frev 
LEFT JOIN incros on inmast.fpartno+inmast.frev=incros.fpartno+incros.fcpartrev
LEFT JOIN jomast on sorels.fstatus=jomast.fjobno 
LEFT JOIN joitem on jomast.fjobno=joitem.fjobno
LEFT JOIN jodrtg on jomast.fjobno=jodrtg.fjobno 
LEFT JOIN inwork on jodrtg.fpro_id=inwork.fcpro_id
LEFT JOIN slcdpmx on somast.fcustno=slcdpmx.fcustno  
LEFT JOIN syphon ON somast.fcontact=syphon.fcontact AND somast.fcustno=syphon.fcsourceid 
LEFT JOIN syaddr ON 'SLCDPM    '+somast.fcustno+'S'+sorels.fshptoaddr=syaddr.fcalias+syaddr.fcaliaskey+syaddr.fcaddrtype+syaddr.fcaddrkey 
--*/

WHERE LEFT(somast.fstatus,1)<>'C' 
and fsocoord<>'IFP' and fsocoord<>'711' 

Order by cte1.EarliestDate, sorels.fsono, BackOrd, sorels.finumber, sorels.frelease
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it.

```
Select  AllData.*,
        earliest.mismatch
from    #mytable    AllData
    left join
        (Select NAME, 
                min(date) mismatch
        from    #mytable
        where   [ts] <> [TO]
        group by
                NAME) earliest         on AllData.Name = earliest.Name
```